# Typo3 Powermail: " is shown as &quote;

Tags: typo3, quote

If there is a " in the Mail, it is shown as & quote ;
I know this is for security, but is there a way to still get a " without reducing the security?

Typo3 Version: 4.5
Powermail Version: 1.6.8

Comment: I've had the same problem in one of these old Powermail versions. The problem was that htmlspecialchars() was used two times. I fixed it by removing one of the two uses, but I can't tell you were exactly I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Powermail 1.6 (escapes text twice).
It's fixed in future versions.

If you'd rather not upgrade to 2.x, as you won't be able to migrate content, you can get the 1.7 branch which is quite hidden but well maintained.

http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-powermail/repository/show?rev=1.7